# Как расчитать требуемый буфер для Unicode перед передачей в _snwprintf_s？

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++, форматирование

Я подумал, что раз в си можно рассчитать требуемый буфер с помощью `snprintf`, то такой же вариант прокатит и с функцией [`_snwprintf_s`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l?view=vs-2019), но как оказалось, при приведенном ниже кодом, данная функция всегда будет возвращать 0.

```
::size_t size_needed = ::_snwprintf_s(nullptr, 0u, 0u, L"me_window_class[%s]", application_name);
m_class_name_.resize(size_needed + 1u);
::_snwprintf_s(&m_class_name_.front(), m_class_name_.size(), _TRUNCATE, L"me_window_class[%s]", application_name);
```

Как это можно провернуть не прибегая к использованию `std::stringstream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть функция [_scwprintf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scprintf-scprintf-l-scwprintf-scwprintf-l?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Как я понимаю, префикс говорит о возврате размера, верно?

Comment: @ヒミコ причем она ничего не печатает, только считает нужный размер